# Indicator Function appearing when solving functional equation

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $I_A(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \in A\\1 & \text{else} \end{cases}$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}.$

A particularly hard functional equation boiled down to determining the sets $A$ satisfying $I_A(x)I_A(x+y)=I_A(y)I_A(x-y).$ Due to analysis of the original functional equation, we know that $I_A(0)=1,$ or $0 \notin A.$

I have determined the following properties:

$I_A(x) = I_A(-x),$ or $x \in A \iff -x \in A$

$x \in A \Rightarrow x/2 \in A$

If $a \in A,$ then $I_A(x)I_A(a-x)=I_A(x)I_A(a+x)=0.$

I've noticed that if A is non-empty, it will contain arbitrarily large and small values. Thus, I've conjectured that the only possible $A$ that satisfy the aforementioned indicational equation are $\emptyset, \, \mathbb{R} \setminus 0.$

Comment: Your notation looks a little backwards. What you have written for as $I_A$ is a function that takes on $1$ when $x \not \in A$. This is fine it's just not the typical definition. Is that what you intended? Typically we might write such a function as $I_\bar{A}$ where $\bar{A}$ refers to the complement of $A$.

Comment: @Mason Yes. The solution to the original functional equation is $I_A(x)\gamma(x),$ where $\gamma>0$ is a positive function that we already found.

Comment: Can $A$ be the set of irrational numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The set of all rationals numbers and the set of all dyadic rationals numbers both satisfy the given equation. There are many solutions.

Comment: I was just fixing to answer this with the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational

Comment: No I think you are reading the "indicator function" backwards tho... 

$I_\mathbb{Q}(\pi)I_\mathbb{Q}(\pi+\pi)=1\times 1 \neq I_\mathbb{Q}(\pi)I_\mathbb{Q}(\pi-\pi)=1\times 0 $

Comment: The complements of these sets do the trick. This confusion is the result of the OP defining the indicator function in precisely the opposite of the conventional notation.

Comment: Very strange definition of indicator function by the OP. Thanks to Mason. My answer can be corrected by taking complements. I would not correct my answer because the OP has confused us by not sticking to standard convention.